# Confusion while importing functions of another file and use it in other file

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I create two functions DoublePi, TriplePi and a variable pi in Math.js file and export the variable as default and the other two functions export normally.

When I import them into index.js file and want to use the values of DoublePi and TriplePi we have to use a () bracket to call the function for use as bellow -

Math.js file ------------>

```
    const pi = 3.141;

function DoublePi() {
  return 2 * pi;
}

function TriplePi() {
  return 3 * pi;
}

export default pi;

export { DoublePi, TriplePi };
```

index.js code--------->

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import pi, { DoublePi, TriplePi } from "./Math";

ReactDOM.render(
  <ul>
    <li>{pi}</li>
    <li>{DoublePi()}</li>
    <li>{TriplePi()}</li>
  </ul>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

But when we import other functions like App and use the value of App function we don't use the () bracket there why?

App.jsx ------>

```
    import React from "react";
import Heading from "./Heading";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Heading />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js ---------->

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```